# How to check if access token is expired or not in android

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

I am using `oauth2.0` system to make network calls. I have the `token expire time` i.e: `2096 sec`. Now before I make any network call using `Volley`. I want to check whether the token is expired or not. How can I calculate that using the `expire time` provided to me through the API ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can try is save the time when you get the token in the shared preferences as the "refresh_time" and when you make a network call. just check using the condition

```
    float refresh_time=Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
    saveRefreshTime(refresh_time);
    //when you refresh the token use the code written above

    float current_time=Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();


    float newTime=current_time-refresh_time/1000;

    float bufferTime=100;
    if(newTime<(2096-bufferTime)){

        //DO your network call
    }
    else{
        //refresh the token

    }
```

the buffer_time can be anytime like 100 seconds for safer side

Comment: current_time and refresh_time should be in seconds ?

Comment: no just use the time stamp and date comparison time in miliseconds and use the standard formula to convert milis to second, its just divide by 1000

Comment: can you elaborate a little on current_time and refresh_time please.

Comment: I am using `System.currentTimeMillis()`. is that fine ?

Comment: What would happen if user changes the system time, in that case it will fail right?